# Deploying a ruby/rails site on register.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im new to rails as well as relatively new to web development. Anywho, I've fully developed a site utilizing js, jquery, and rails and now Im hoping to use register.com as the host for it however Im a bit confused on how to go about this. Could someone who perhaps has dealth with register.com and rails provide me with a bit of insight as to how to go about this.

Thanks and sorry for the vagueness of the question im just confused on how to move my project from my computer to register.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using heroku.com instead. Register.com is meant for static webpages, not web applications. Heroku can host your app for free unless you require more resources. You'll just need to buy a domain name. Check it out!

Comment: Thanks appreciate it I was originally using heroku but the client Im constructing the site for already had a register account setup and everything so I was curious to see if it was possible to do it on there. But as I said the distinctions between hosts is something of obscurity to me so I appreciate you dropping a little knowledge on me !